# Propierties of limits ad infinitum

Tags: real-analysis

I know that 
$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow c}f(x) + \lim_{x\rightarrow c}g(x) = \lim_{x\rightarrow c}(f(x)+g(x))$$ holds when $c$ is finite but also is true when $c$ is $\infty$?

Comment: Yes. Do you know the proof when $c$ is finite? It's a very instructive exercise to adapt that proof to the case $x\to\infty$.

Comment: No at all, it has to do with the difference quotient and adding a special zero? I think I view that in some place.

Comment: That is true when all the limits exist. Take $f(x)=\sin(1/x)$ for $x$ nonzero and $f(0)=0$. Define $g(x)=1-f(x)$. Then $f(x)+g(x)=1=\text{const.}$ certainly has a limit of $1$ everywhere, even though neither $f(x)$ nor $g(x)$ have limit for $x\to 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gets tricky.

If $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = -x$, then

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) + \lim_{x \to \infty}g(x) = \infty - \infty$$

And $$\lim_{x \to \infty}\left( f(x) + g(x)\right) = \lim_{x \to \infty}0 = 0$$

And recall $\infty - \infty$ is an [indeterminate form](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form) so we can't just say that it is equal to $0$

Comment: I think that would be fixed if we assume that the limit exists, that is $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x)= \alpha$ where $\alpha$ is finite.

Comment: Indeed. I didn't see any such assumptions, hence why I provided my answer

Comment: That is because I was searching for the general case. And you example give a better understanding. Thanks.